# How can I make a list of integers click on element with corresponding id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of ids (integer) and I have multiple  components.
After a request to my API, the  component receives a list of ids that should already be active.
I want to simulate a click on each element with the same id as the one in my array. I know I can use refs to do that, but I don't undertstand how to make it works with a list of elements.

Here's my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import InterestBox from './InterestBox'
import Axios from 'axios'

export class InterestList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {pinterests: []}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/interests')
        .then((success) => {
            this.setState({pinterests: success.data.data.interests});
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(prevProps));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props))
        if(this.props.alreadyChecked != prevProps.alreadyChecked) {
            this.props.alreadyChecked.forEach((item) => {
                console.log(item)
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {Object.keys(this.state.pinterests).map((interest) => {
                    var pinterest = this.state.pinterests[interest];
                    return <InterestBox id={pinterest.id} onClick={this.props.onClick} icon={pinterest.picture_src} title={pinterest.name} />
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default InterestList
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export class InterestBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.images = require('../../img/interests/*.svg');

        this.state = {activated: false};
        this.interest_box_content = React.createRef();
        this.interest_text = React.createRef();
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.props.handleClick(this.props.id, this.props.title);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            activated: !prevState.activated
        }))        
    }

    updateDimensions() {
        console.log((window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.interest_box_content).width))
        this.refs.interest_text = (window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.interest_box_content).width)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="column is-one-fifth-desktop is-half-touch">
                <div className="interest-box">
                    <div className="interest-box-adjuster">
                        <div ref={"interest_box_content"} className={"interest-box-content " + (this.state.activated == true ? 'interest-box-activated' : '')} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <img className="interest-icon" src={this.images[this.props.icon]} style={{'height': '50%'}}></img>
                            <i className="activated-icon fas fa-check"></i>
                            <span ref={"interest_text"} className="interest-text">{this.props.title}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default InterestBox
```

In the InterestList "componentDidUpdate" method, the value of the item is an integer.
I want to use this integer to "click" on the InterestBox with the corresponding "id".

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to simulate a click on it?

Comment: I need it to trigger that activated state of the InterestBox (so it can change appearance) and to trigger the onClick method passed from the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store an array of elements in one ref, like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {pinterests: []}
  this.pinterestRefs = React.createRef()
}

...

render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {Object.keys(this.state.pinterests).map((interest) => {
                    var pinterest = this.state.pinterests[interest];
                    return <InterestBox id={pinterest.id} onClick={this.props.onClick} icon={pinterest.picture_src} title={pinterest.name} ref={pinterestRef => this.refs.pinterestRefs.push(pinterestRef)} />
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

and then call the click function on each in a `componentDidMount` function:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.refs.pinterestRefs.length) {
    this.refs.pinterestRefs.forEach(pinterestEl => {
      pinterestEl.click();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It tells me that "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". I will try to find a solution for that... I think I did everything properly though.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about how to use refs in classes, because I'm used to hooks :). The syntax might be a little different, but I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Since `this.pinterestRefs` is a ref and not an array, the `push` method is not available. Unfortunately, we do not have a definite length so we can't declare the refs preemptively. However, we can add it to `this.refs` object and the convert it to an array:

```
export class InterestList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {pinterests: []}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/interests')
        .then((success) => {
            this.setState({pinterests: success.data.data.interests});
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log(Object.values(this.refs)); // Array with all refs
        console.log(JSON.stringify(prevProps));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props))
        if(this.props.alreadyChecked != prevProps.alreadyChecked) {
            this.props.alreadyChecked.forEach((item) => {
                console.log(item)
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            {/*I'm assuming each item has a unique id, if not, create one*/}
            <React.Fragment>
                {Object.keys(this.state.pinterests).map((interest) => {
                    var pinterest = this.state.pinterests[interest];
                    return <InterestBox id={pinterest.id} onClick={this.props.onClick} ref={pinterest.id} icon={pinterest.picture_src} title={pinterest.name} />
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default InterestList;
```