# How can I store a ref in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code, I have multiple  components with each of them a different id. 
I need to attach each of them a ref. However, I get an error that says :

```
TypeError: _this3.pinterestRefs.push
```

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import InterestBox from './InterestBox'
import Axios from 'axios'

export class InterestList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {pinterests: []}
        this.pinterestRefs = React.createRef()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/interests')
        .then((success) => {
            this.setState({pinterests: success.data.data.interests});
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(prevProps));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props))
        if(this.props.alreadyChecked != prevProps.alreadyChecked) {
            this.props.alreadyChecked.forEach((item) => {
                console.log(item)
            })
        }
        console.log(this.refs)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {Object.keys(this.state.pinterests).map((interest) => {
                    var pinterest = this.state.pinterests[interest];
                    return <InterestBox id={pinterest.id} onClick={this.props.onClick} icon={pinterest.picture_src} title={pinterest.name} ref={pinterestRef => this.pinterestRefs.push(pinterestRef)} />
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default InterestList
```

How am I supposed to solve this issue ?

To understand why I am doing this : [How can I make a list of integers click on element with corresponding id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521202/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-integers-click-on-element-with-corresponding-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you need to understand how refs work. A ref **object** is simply an object React keeps in between renders. It is an object that looks like `{ current: null }`. So you can assign anything to the current property.

If a ref **attribute** is passed a ref **object** (e.g. `React.createRef()`), the ref **object's** `current` is set to the DOM element of the component.

If a ref **attribute** is passed a ref **function**, the function is passed the DOM element of the component.

In this case you need to initially assign an array to the ref object created and use callback refs to assign the values in `render()`

```
export class InterestList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        /* Other constructor code */
        this.pinterestRef = React.createRef();
        this.pinterestRef.current = []; // This is the array to keep the nodes we want to store
    }

    /* Rest of component code */

    render () {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {Object.keys(this.state.pinterests).map((interest, i) => {
                    var pinterest = this.state.pinterests[interest];
                    var callbackRef = node => pinterestRef.current[i] = node; // This function will be passed our node that is stored in the pinterestRef.current at index "i"
                    return <InterestBox id={pinterest.id} onClick={this.props.onClick} icon={pinterest.picture_src} title={pinterest.name} ref={callbackRef} />
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this.pinterestRefs = React.createRef() in you constructor.

pinterestRefs is not an array, you can't push into it.

I'm not too familiar with react, but from the following link your answer might be on the first comment: https://dev.to/ajsharp/-an-array-of-react-refs-pnf